# Postgresql UPSERT while encrypting column by python encryption

Tags: python, postgresql, encryption, upsert

I am using BULK UPSERT to insert record into new table while data of column is being encrypting by python lib CryptoDome.
here is what I done

```
def bulk_upsert_query(data, table_name=None):
    values_list = []
    add = values_list.append

    for i in data:
        encrypt_user_id = encryption_fnc(str(i.user_id))

        add(f"({i.id},'{encrypt_user_id}','{i.name}')")

    upsert_sql = r"""insert into upsert_test_table 
                    (id,encrypt_user_id,name)
                   values
                   """ + "\n, ".join(values_list) + """ ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT 
                  "upsert_test_table_pkey"
                   DO UPDATE SET
                   name=excluded.name,
                   encrypt_user_id=excluded.user_id"""
    return upsert_sql
```

data = data from my old table that have *user_id* as int(ex: 124,345,786)
in `upsert_test_table` table id column is primary key column.
this `bulk_upsert_query` fnc will encrypt int *user_id* and append to values_list then create a upsert query.

As per insertion it works as I expected, but when it comes for update if conflict with id column then as you can see I set `encrypt_user_id=excluded.user_id` for *user_id* column,
it update existing encrypted *user_id* with int *user_id*(from old table), because I did not put any encryption fnc here,
**Update**: user_id column is changeable

So what I want is I want to call my `encryption_fnc` in `DO UPDATE SET` section,
while it update I also want to do encryption.

Can any one tell me who can I achieve this?

**Note**: I can do encryption in database site by using `pgcrypto` but my requirement is do encryption in python side not database side.

Comment: Offtopic: Are you 100% sure this piece of SQL isn't prone to SQL-injection?

Comment: @FrankHeikens Sorry I am not well knowledge about sql- injection  but this function will execute manually for 1/2 times only, so I am not very concerned about sql injections here. thanks for your concern , if you have any suggestions I am all hear.

Comment: You don't have a `user_id` column in your insert payload. `encrypt_user_id=excluded.user_id` is therefore inserting a `null` rather than the old, unencrypted `user_id`. [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ORuzmMFa). Have you tried replacing that with `encrypt_user_id=excluded.encrypt_user_id`? You already have an encrypted user_id for that row in your payload, why not point to that

Comment: @Zegarek I have ```user_id``` column in my insert payload(data), and I insert that column into new table by encrypting(user_id), you said replacing ```excluded.user_id``` with ```excluded.encrypt_user_id``` here ```excluded``` indicate your original data source that have unencrypted ```user_id``` column, not ```encrypt_user_id``` column.

Comment: @Zegarek sorry, I was stupid, I tired by replacing ```excluded.user_id``` with ```excluded.encrypt_user_id``` and it works, although have no idea how ```excluded``` table works, thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved:
Sorry I was stupid, I thought `excluded` table is original(input payload) table, but when I replaced `excluded.user_id` with `excluded.encrypt_user_id` and it works, although have no idea how excluded table works.

```
upsert_sql = r"""insert into upsert_test_table 
                    (id,encrypt_user_id,name)
                   values
                   """ + "\n, ".join(values_list) + """ ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT 
                  "upsert_test_table_pkey"
                   DO UPDATE SET
                   name=excluded.name,
                   encrypt_user_id=excluded.encrypt_user_id"""
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76052051/postgresql-upsert-while-encrypting-column-by-python-encryption#comment134129072_76052051):
there is no `user_id` column in that insert payload, so `excluded.user_id` is `null`.

`ON CONFLICT...DO UPDATE SET encrypt_user_id=excluded.user_id` is inserting a `null` rather than the old, unencrypted `user_id`: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/q5-c8HTB)

```sql
CREATE TABLE upsert_test_table 
  (id SMALLSERIAL,
  encrypt_user_id TEXT,
  name TEXT,
  user_id INT,
  CONSTRAINT "upsert_test_table_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id));
INSERT INTO upsert_test_table VALUES 
  (1,'enc1','Bob',11);

INSERT INTO upsert_test_table (id,encrypt_user_id,name) VALUES
  (1,'enc101','Bob2'),--conflict here
  (2,'enc2','Ted')
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT "upsert_test_table_pkey"
DO UPDATE SET 
  name = excluded.name,              --name will be overwritten by incoming data
  encrypt_user_id = excluded.user_id;--null because user_id not in incoming data

SELECT * FROM upsert_test_table;
-- id | encrypt_user_id | name | user_id
------+-----------------+------+---------
--  1 |                 | Bob2 |      11
--  2 | enc2            | Ted  |
```

From [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT):

> The `SET` and `WHERE` clauses in `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` have access to the existing row using the table's name (or an alias), and to the row proposed for insertion using the special `excluded` table.

The issue here was that `excluded` was misunderstood and instead used as the preexisting data found already in the table upon conflict, while it's actually the data that was coming in, as the payload of that insert.

It should be enough to correct that one misinterpretation and refer to new/incoming/inserted value as `excluded`, old/existing by the target table name and column:

```python
upsert_sql = r"""insert into upsert_test_table 
                (id,encrypt_user_id,name)
               values
               """ + "\n, ".join(values_list) + """ ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT 
              "upsert_test_table_pkey"
               DO UPDATE SET
               name = upsert_test_table.name,             --keep the old name
               encrypt_user_id = excluded.encrypt_user_id --overwrite with new
              """
```